# javascript proxy on jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy

I have a jQuery plugin and I need to change it's default settings (and force these defaults settings for every instance of the plugin). Modifying its source code is not an option (updates etc), so I figured that if I proxy'd it, I would be home. So I looked up for an example, how you do that in JS:

```
var proxied = jQuery.ajax; // Preserving original function
jQuery.ajax = function() { 
    jQuery("#loading").dialog({modal: true});
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Now this code is quite straightforward, but

**I'm not sure how can I proxy "element method", like** `$(".select").multiselect();` **in similar fashion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I searched a bit more and found the answer myself.

All jQuery object methods are "stored" in `jQuery.fn` object. So all I had to do was

```
var proxied = jQuery.fn.multiselect;
jQuery.fn.multiselect = function() {
    // stuff
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments); 
};
```

Hope somebody finds that helpful!